# Boot into advanced startup menu Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot

Is there any way to boot into the advanced startup menu in Windows 10?
I did some research and a couple of websites say that after 3 failed boots, windows will automatically boot into this menu. However, this is not happening for me.

Some websites also said that pressing F8 or Shift + F8 or F11 at splash screen should do the trick depending on the laptop manufacturer. This did not help either.

The advanced startup options screen for reference:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  Please take a few minutes to read through this tutorial:  [How to Boot to Advanced Startup Options in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html).  It lists several different methods, and the author (Shawn Brink) is a Microsoft MVP who provides some of the most reliable Windows tutorials on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new shortcut with:

**shutdown.exe** /r /o /f /t 0

```
shutdown /?
/r      Full shutdown and restart the computer
/o      Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
/f      Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
/fw     Combine with a shutdown option to cause the next boot to go to the firmware ui.
/t xxx  Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
```

**Update**:
*OP mentioned his laptop is crashing and can't even boot, so the original question is deceiving.*

For that case, this would be more fitting answer:

You just have to keep at it.
Because it's a laptop, it's harder since you don't have a reset button.
After Power ON keep holding the button pressed until shutdown.
It's needed 3 times, and timing is everything.

If still unsuccessful you should check out your laptop manual and find what key brings you to BIOS/UEFI setup. Then spam that key as soon as you hit the power button. Once in BIOS/UEFI, disable any Fast Boot options.

Another solution would be to connect an external keyboard - it's usually more reliable.

And finally, connecting a bootable device such as a dvd or usb stick can also break the loop. There is probably also a hotkey to launch a boot menu, such as ESC, F1, F2, F8, F11, F12.

Comment: I failed to read the parameter description for /o my aplogizes.

Comment: This is possible only if I can boot into Windows right? The laptop I am using crashes in less than a minute and restarts immediately after a driver installation failure. In the minute it is on, I am unable to do anything. Even the desktop does not load completely. I would like to go back to the previous restore point through the advanced boot options menu.

Comment: You did not mentioned you're crashing in OP.   
In that case, you just have to keep at it.  
Because it's a laptop, it's harder since you don't have a reset button.  
After Power ON keep holding the button pressed until shutdown.  
It's needed 3 times, and timing is everything.  
If still unsuccessful you should check out your laptop manual and find what key brings you to BIOS/UEFI setup.  
Then spam that key as soon as you hit the power button. Once in BIOS/UEFI, disable any Fast Boot options.  
Another solution would be to connect an external keyboard - it's usually more reliable.

Comment: @AveYo my apologies for the deceiving question. So just to clarify, I have to hold the power button and power my laptop off 3 times in a row and hope that the fourth time it boots into advanced boot options menu. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes. Note that if the Windows installation is borked completely there is no Windows boot menu anymore to get to - in that case you need to boot from external setup media.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to boot into the advanced startup menu in Windows 10?

1. Launch Settings
2. Search for "Advanced Startup"

[image]

3. Press the **Restart now** button

[image]

4. Done